# Reference a global query as data within subsequent queries?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, syntax, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

A simple query

> =QUERY(data, query, [headers])

I would like to externalize a QUERY, to make it global.

The QUERY is used as data within other subsequent queries

Such as

> =QUERY2(**QUERY1(data, query, [headers])**, query, [headers])

Becomes

> =QUERY2(A1, query, [headers])

Where, as a string

> A1 = "QUERY1(data, query, [headers])"

I've tried

> =QUERY2(**"'&A1&'"**, query, [headers])

But it doesn't work.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formula (in your case the subquery) written as a text string cannot be converted into actual formula or range without a script that turns plain text string into a fully functional formula. google sheets in the current operating version does not possess an internal mechanism that would read the formula like below, and render it as a function

```
=QUERY("QUERY(data, query, [headers])", query, [headers])
```

an example of the script would be:

```
function onEdit() { 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');  
var src = sheet.getRange("C4");    // The cell which holds the formula
var str = src.getValue();  
var cell = sheet.getRange("C5");   // The cell where I want the results to be
cell.setFormula(str);              // Setting the formula.
}
```

but then C4 would need to be written as:

```
="=QUERY("&A1&", ""select *"", 1)"
```